# Creating a CSV with Irish Grid references and opening the points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a load of Irish grid references that I need to create a map of in Ireland - any advice? Tried to input a couple of refs and open in Biological record tool thinking this would be simple but hey ho, I'm asking for help now!
See the CSV example - what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Remove the letters in the coordinates (eg. `E296351` should just be `296351`). To add the csv file to QGIS, go to _Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer..._ making sure the **First record has field names** option is selected. Define your point `X` and `Y` fields in the Geometry definition and pray it works :)

Comment: Thanks Joseph - did try this also, but then I get issues with the fields, whereby the Northings also has 296351 in it, from cell B2?

Comment: You may need to _clean up_ your csv file, the `X` and `Y` fields should only contain coordinates.

Comment: Ok, so the cvs only has the numbers in, no letters or names, still the fields are field_1, coordinates in B1 and A2, or field_3.

Comment: and states that there is no data found in file...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what your csv file looks like please? Hopefully others can also advise :)

Comment: Just a 4x4 table with six digits references in each... therefore two grid points.

Comment: please see new csv added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshots it looks like you're on a Mac, using Excel. When saving a CSV from Mac Excel, you have to select the 'Windows comma separated' format instead of the first CSV option in the save-as list ... otherwise QGIS doesn't interpret the file correctly.

[image]

Comment: It's a super-annoying problem that loses me a little time every week!